# android local permission Androidmanifest SMS READ

Tags: android

Configuration:

- Studio 1.3
- API 23

I am learning Android and started working on SMS read a simple project.

I have added the permissions in the SMS_READ in the AndroidManifest.xml. Still when run emulator it throwing error permission denial for SMS_READ.

I am not sure that emulator problem or API 23 level permission change?

Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.telephony.SmsProvider uri content://sms/inbox from pid=1900, uid=10058 requires android.permission.READ_SMS, or grantUriPermission()
            at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
            at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
            at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
            at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:421)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:491)
            at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:434)
            at com.example.gunda.mysmsreadapp.MainActivity.fetchInbox(MainActivity.java:68)
            at com.example.gunda.mysmsreadapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Here is the manifest xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.gunda.mysmsreadapp" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        android:exported="true"

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <!--<action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.READ_SMS" />-->
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: According to the LogCat it should be: `requires android.permission.READ_SMS` and not `SMS_READ` as you mention.

Comment: The `android:exported` attribute seems to be misplaced. Should it be inside the `application` tag?

Answer (score 3):

at last i found the answer:
API 23 (android 6.o) required different type of permission.....

http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en

Comment: @Venu you should assign this or other answer as the correct one for the future reader to have a better guidance.

Comment: You should probably also make it clear that you won't get approval from Google to use this permission.

Answer (score 0):

Permission name is READ_SMS it seems you are using SMS_READ.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>  I have provided it.

Comment: @Venu He meant, edit your question, and paste how your AndroidManifest.xml file is. It seems that there is some error in your permissions, most likely a wrong open/close markup.... also a minor detail, if you are using Android Studio, click `ctrl` + `alt` + `L` to auto format code

Answer (score 0):

Just update here -if you want to use READ_SMS permission then you request Google with declaration why your app needs this permission, then they give access to your app. read this [support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9214102](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9214102)

Comment: To make it explicitly, clear, you're never going to get approval for this permission unless you're a large financial institution or a phone manufacturer. Just resign yourself to the fact, and remove the functionality. (Probably for good reason, now that SMS is commonly used for 2FA authentication).